# How to add eclipse-source javadoc to java-build-path in?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, javadoc

I have an Eclipse RCP Project. 
I am using Eclipse source classes, for that I am have a target platform with Eclipse's update site. 
The plugins are imported from the target site, but without the Javadoc.

**Quesion:** 
What is the location of the Eclipse's Javadoc for Eclipse RCP classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a checkbox to import the sources, inside of teh target platform's update-site dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Javadoc for a jar
It is also possible to add Javadoc to a library which you use.

Download the Javadoc of the jar and put it somewhere in your filesystem.

Open the Java Build Path page of a project via Right click on a project → Properties → Java Build Path. On the Libraries tab expand the library's node, select the Javadoc location attribute and press the Edit button.

Enter the location to the file which contains the Javadoc.

sourcepath="D:/eclipse3.3.2/plugins/org.eclipse.rcp.source_3.3.3.r33x_r20080129-8y8eE9UEUWI6qujeED0xT7bc/src/org.eclipse.osgi_3.3.2.R33x_v20080105/src.zip"

just try to adapte this to your case.